# Android : Handle Locale on Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am using `Fragments` and `DialogFragments` in  my app. I also want to support various languages. When the user changes locale the `Fragment` is updated accordingly. But the `DialogFragment` is dismissed!

I have tried `setRetainInstance(true);` but this is killing the dialog which is active.

My `MainFragment`:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button mButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        mButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(MainFragment.this);
        return v;

    }

    void showDialog() {
        CustomDialog newFragment = CustomDialog.newInstance();
        newFragment.listner = new ISubmitListner() {

            @Override
            public void onButtonClick() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " OK pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog();
    }
}
```

My `CustomDialog`:

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
    ISubmitListner listner;

    public static CustomDialog getInstance(Bundle bundle) {
        CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog();
        dialog.setArguments(bundle);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    static CustomDialog newInstance() {
        return new CustomDialog();
    }

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setView(new View(getActivity()));
        mProgressDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title));
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.message));
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light);
        mProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        mProgressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                listner.onButtonClick();

            }
        });

        return mProgressDialog;
    }
}
```

And my `ISubmitListner`:

```
public interface ISubmitListner {
    void onButtonClick();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, what do you mean with "how do i retain the dialog with new config of Locale"?

Comment: The user changes the Locale by pressing a button that causes the dialog to get dismissed?The dialog does remain there, but you want to use the new Locale and it doesn't?Where exactly do you use that?

Comment: In your dialog, what your showing which depends over the local? If whole dialog text is dependent over the local, you have to re-initiate it.

Comment: @XaverKapeller i want to show the fragment with dialog even after user changes Locale, with new language.

Comment: @421 So what's the problem? Can't you just show us some relevant code? How is anybody supposed to help you if we don't know what you are doing?

Comment: @ThomasKaliakos user is changing the locale from decive settings and as the configuration is changed,fragment is re-created.Due to fragment recreation i am not display the dialog with new locale.As it is getting dismissed.

Comment: @421 Show us some code and we might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: @jitainsharma This dialog displays network down message and stops user to browse application offline.

Comment: @XaverKapeller sure. i'll add my code.

Comment: Is your Dialog is a custom dialog, if yes, inside your dialog class, create a method for repopulate the dialog texts views with new local, or apply the listener for locale change and re-populate the view texts. And if not, just re-open the dialog again after local change.

Comment: Is your problem solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-instantiate the dialog as locale config changes will restart the activities and consequently will remove all the dialogs on the activity.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you should ask yourself if this is even a problem. Users rarely change their locale if they do it at all. So that the `DialogFragment` is dismissed when changing the locale seems like a rather minor issue. I wouldn't worry about it.

---

But anyway here is a solution:

Override `onConfigurationChanged` in your `Fragment` like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

This method is called every time the user changes the configuration. This can be changing the locale or orientation. You can get information about the new configuration from the `Configuration` object:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    final Locale locale = newConfig.locale;
    final int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
    ...
}
```

You can check in there if the `DialogFragment` was just dismissed and if it was just reopen it.

Comment: This code  i have tried,but language is not getting updated,tough i call update configuration method in onConfigurationChanged

Answer (score 0):

call **changeAppLanguage(...)** Method in `onCreate(){}` please!

It works well.

```
Resources resources = getContext().getResources();

DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
} else {
    configuration.locale = locale;
}
resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very bad practice to do. Android is not designed to behave in that manner. You need to reconfigure the layout after changing the locale. You can show a dialog to close the app and restart it. These will be standard way to do it.